# UTF-8 on old MFC project converted to newer MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, utf-8

So project is Multi-byte by design. Recode full project to Unicode is to big work :(

So how can I use UTF-8 on my dialogs ? I've got this :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with UTF8 code page. But, since I'm not sure how you pass ??? texts to the dialog, this might not be a solution. Similarly, if you try to pass UTF8 string to where MultiByte expected, you can try [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with UTF8 code page.

Comment: I just edit it with Visual Studio designer. Sorry I fixed it - changed dialog locale to this language.